# MySQL can't create table, it seems already exist

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table using the following command :

```
CREATE TABLE oc_migrations (
    app VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    version VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(app, version)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Output me the following error:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table
> 'MY_DB.oc_migrations' (errno: -1)

But I can create it sucessfully if I create the table in a different name:

```
CREATE TABLE oc_migrations_new_name (
    app VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    version VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(app, version)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_bin ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Output:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------------+
| Tables_in_MY_DB             |
+-----------------------------+
| oc_migrations_new_name      |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't know why I can't create a table under the name `oc_migrations` even if he doesn't exist. But under a different table name it work

**EDIT:**

Accessing my db files `/var/lib/mysql/MY_DB` I have the following file : `oc_migrations.ibd`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table "x" (errno: -1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352733/error-1005-hy000-cant-create-table-x-errno-1)

Comment: Yes I know the name is different, I pointed it in my question

Comment: So whoever voted to close as a typo should retract that ;-)

Comment: @Progman I'm not facing the same situation

Comment: See here: https://www.wedevelop.coffee/2019/02/23/resolve-general-error-1005-cant-create-table-errno-150-in/ maybe can help you

Comment: @executable Do you use a Nextcloud server?

Comment: @executable Why do you think it is not the same situation or at least related to it? Also, have you checked the installation directory of your MySQL server and check the existing database files?

Comment: @AdamP. Yes the table is coming from Nextcloud. I got the error at the installation and then I tried to create it manually for debugging

Comment: did you try a simple `drop` on the table name you want to use?

Comment: Yep ```mysql> drop table oc_migrations;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'oc_migrations'``` and then I tried to recreate it, same issue

Comment: Accessing my db files `/var/lib/mysql/MY_DB` I have the following file : oc_migrations.ibd

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation like this once; my mysqld server crashed while I was creating a table, and the table name got stuck like this.

Here's a way to diagnose this problem.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE();
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

The offending table name shows up as a VIEW in this result set. The Warnings say something like this:

> 'Warning', 1932, 'Table whatever doesn't exist in engine

Going into the  file system of the server and deleting the `whatever.frm` and `whatever.ibd` files clears up the problem for me, immediately, without restarting the server.

Truth be told, I don't much like deleting files out from under complex server software like MySQL. So, I try to move them to a recycle bin or something, in case I muck it up.

Comment: If I delete `oc_migrations.ibd`, I will have to restart the daemon ? I'm afraid to corrupt the service

Comment: I did not have to restart my daemon to fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll give a try